# Blank Camera Persp

Tags: camera

I have been at this for hours. I have an issue with one of my blend files I seems that when I switch to camera persp I see only a blank screen.
[image]

If I open a default startup.blend everything works fine and I can see the objects as normal in the camera persp.

I've tried opening both my file as well as a default file and tried checking all of the settings and properties.

I've googled this and still can't find a solution. I've tried checking all of the standard answers, "clipping", "shift", etc.

I'll try and attach my blend file.

[image]

I should also add that everything seems to render fine, it's just if I preview it from the the camera persp (Numpad 0). This is case for each scene.

Comment: What happens if you press Home button while hovering the mouse over the 3d View?

Comment: Oh my gosh! That was probably the one thing I haven't tried. I don't know why cause I use the Home button all the time in the VSE to correct the view. I have spent hours searching google and checking all the settings. I can't believe it was so simple.
Thank You very much.